# Preventing component update when underlying data model changes

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I am building a questionnaire which has conditional visibility rules in Angular 6. I have no control over the data structure that is being provided, nor the business logic which has to be implemented as it is in the current solution I am redeveloping :/

The issue I am having is thus:

- I have this notion of a "visible" questionnaire, which is an array of sections and each section contains an array of questions
- When a question is answered I re-run the visibility rules and create a "temp" array which is of the same base structure as the visible questions array.
- I then use lodash to merge these arrays, thus causing the previously hidden components to now magically appear in the questionnaire.
- This all works fine apart from 1 thing which is really frustrating me, essentially previously answered questions revert back to their unanswered state (Angular is re-drawing them)
- The frustration here is that although the underlying array has mutated, the originally object the element is bound to has not changed. In Vue (using a VDOM) the previously rendered elements don't change, which is what I would expect. But in Angular they do, which I am guessing is due to Angular's Change Detection Strategy.

I have read a few articles on Angular Change Detection, but either I am just not getting it, or my use case is not supported? It's important that the user can still interact with the component, but if the underlying object that the HTML uses for rendering hasn't changed (which it won't) then I don't want it to re-render.

The main thing I have been looking at is `ChangeDetectorRef` and using the `detach()`, `detectChanges()` and `reattach()` methods, and following this blog post https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f

In my parent component I have set `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

Nothing I have tried works. Either the component doesn't render intially (if I use 
`constructor(public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.cd.detach();
 }`

Or I can get it to render but I can't interact with the component. Or I can get it to interact, but then it just resets again when the underlying array is updated.

I'm at a bit of a loss on where to go next. I'd much rather just scrap the thing and use Vue over Angular but alas the Lord of the Sith won't allow me to do that.

Comment: can you please create a demo at https://stackblitz.com of the issue, it would help us to debug the code.

Comment: @AkshayRajput NMot sure I can easily replicate it in a sample, but I'll have a try this afternoon

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you can overcome this by setting an extra property to check wether a "revert" button has been pressed or not, and use this as a flag to set a value 
  - answered: true

And if the "revert" button has been pressed you can change the state of the answered variabel to false in the HTML?

Further more this is more just an idea, there are plenty of ways to overcome this, but since you really haven't provided any code its really difficult to come with a more specific solution to your problem.

Comment: Yeah I tried something similar to this from the article I refer to above. The reason I haven't added any code, is really due to the size and complexity of the data structure, but I'll see if I can pull out a small scale mock up. I'm actually more interested in whether the approach I am taking is the correct one, rather than specific code.

Comment: Yes some sort of, they check for the variable prevLength. You need to check for isAnswered and set this variable as a switcher in your logic for your service when you update from status true to false when pressed on a button.
and then you have to use this as well in the HTML to decide what the UI should show depending on the value of the flag.

Comment: I'll give that a go, I know exactly what you mean, and that is slightly different to what I tried before.